# Travel self-evaluation: let's get critical!

Tags: discussion

You love your site and we love your site, but there is a whole world of people out there who might not even know it exists. When they do find it, their first impression will either scare them away or keep them around. Given this, let's take a hard look at the questions and answers here and make sure newcomers see the site at its best!

Below you'll find a few questions randomly selected from this site. What do you think about each of them and their answers? Are they the best they can be or can they be improved? Would they look interesting and inviting to an outsider or are they a little embarrassing?

Upvote the corresponding post here on meta when we're awesome. Downvote when our content just isn't quite up to par.

Oh, and do comment to let everyone know your thoughts and take part in this conversation. :)

Comment: Actually the it's the zeroth impression that's scared off just about every non-geek traveller I've shown the site too: The term "stackexchange" is a very effective non-geek repellent! I really wish it were possible to have another or an alternate domain. Something dull like "tips" or "advice" or "answers" or "experts" or "qa" ...

Comment: Thanks for your input, everyone! :D

Answer (score 4):

[What is the best source of information for ATM availability?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/6053/what-is-the-best-source-of-information-for-atm-availability)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: A very good question but some details in some answers made wrong assumptions that I added comments to.

Answer (score 3):

[Transfer to Udaipur airport](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/6137/transfer-to-udaipur-airport)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: What type of transfer? Regular or weird hour?

Comment: During the day since there are no flights from Udaipur airport during nighttime (with it being a small airport).

Answer (score 3):

[Do microfibre towels dry quicker and absorb more water?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/6104/do-microfibre-towels-dry-quicker-and-absorb-more-water)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: I like this one as it's something a lot of people query.  However it's bordering on a shopping question in some people's minds, I'm sure.  Also it's not immediately obvious as a travel question, even if it is one a lot of travellers ask.

Comment: I think it's fine, perhaps remove a hyperlink for towel models. I would have just written test results in my answer but I believe manufacturer and model are quite important and had to have been mentioned.

Comment: Generally I also like it, but maybe it is more suited for Outdoor SE

Answer (score 3):

[Israel tourist visa renewal](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/6047/israel-tourist-visa-renewal)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: Perhaps we should extend questions like this - improve the wording to make more sense.

Comment: I felt the accepted answer was based on an assumption and commented that many countries have quite varying rules for "visa runs".

Answer (score 2):

[Is there a convenient ferry between Sardinia and Corsica?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/6194/is-there-a-convenient-ferry-between-sardinia-and-corsica)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: Perhaps we should indicate which direction in the question, if it's not obvious? Also - what is convenient? Some of us would relish the 3am ferry if it saves a few bucks :)

Answer (score 2):

[What time does the train from Yerevan arrive in Tbilisi?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/6105/what-time-does-the-train-from-yerevan-arrive-in-tbilisi)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/763/a-auto-obsolete-answer-notes-for-selected-tags

Comment: You could say it's obsolete, but many train companies have been keeping the same schedule for years.  And it's something we could update.  Google already ages pages that are potentially 'out of date', so in terms of people finding the wrong info and getting annoyed, that's kinda being handled for us.

Comment: The train still has the same schedule as a write. I still know people who need this information. If you know I'm wrong and this info is obsolete then I encourage you to add your own up-to-date answer.

Answer (score 2):

[Getting from Pushkar to Ajmer early in the morning](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/6083/getting-from-pushkar-to-ajmer-early-in-the-morning)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Answer (score 2):

[Do I need to apply for a visa to enter South Korea as a tourist on an Australian passport?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/6063/do-i-need-to-apply-for-a-visa-to-enter-south-korea-as-a-tourist-on-an-australian)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: It's specific and contains words Aussies would search for.

Answer (score 1):

[Is there travel insurance for missed flights?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/6188/is-there-travel-insurance-for-missed-flights)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: This is kind of a generic answer to a generic advice, but marginally useful for non-seasoned travellers.

Answer (score 1):

[Am I allowed to take photos of the Umaid Bhawan Palace premises in Jodhpur without being a guest](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/6079/taking-photos-of-the-umaid-bhawan-palace-premises-in-jodhpur)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: It's not obvious immediately whether it's a photography question, legal question or what.  Also, perhaps we should make it 'taking photos in India' - as it's rather specific, and could be tailored to cater to more users.

Comment: Edited title but I don't agree with part about `taking photos in India`.

Comment: I just figured that when I make changes I bump a question so I'll just post them here for CHAOS members to see them and edit without that result.

Comment: Different countries have different things you can and can't take photos of. Military buildings are often out, sometimes embassies and consulates, sometimes quite random stuff. So I think the specific question is good.